# EMR classpath conflicts

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am running a EMR step(spark submit) with fat shaded jar but old version of libraries from EMR gets picked up causing NoSuchMethod exceptions

I tried shading jar and set below but nothing seem to work. Old versions on EMR are loaded first

spark.driver.userClassPathFirst &
spark.executor.userClassPathFirst

How to ensure classes in app jar get precedence over EMR libraries

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configs:

```
spark.driver.userClassPathFirst / spark.executor.userClassPathFirst
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?